# global variable is undefined

Tags: python

```
import socket
import sys
import urllib


port = 6669
mac = "e448c7a96170"

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ip = socket.gethostbyname( mac  + '.rtn.iptv.svt.sciatl.com')
    sock.connect((ip, port))
    print(ip)
    sock.send("getdom;ipg")
    print "Message Sent"
    while True:
        global m;
        m=sock.recv(10000)
    print(m)
    sock.close()
except:
    print sys.exc_info()
```

Hi folks I am new to the python.I am trying to print the 'm' value.But it is not printing it since the print statement is outside the loop. 
I am trying to store the received data in a global variable and use it in the later part.But I am not able to do as the 'm' variable is not visible outside.Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `global m` doesn't makes any sense here. `global` is for functions.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary for *within* functions. (Deleting this comment in a few when you've edited)

Comment: @phant0m oh! I missed the 5 minute mark, btw thanks for pointing out the grammatical mistakes in my sentences for the nth time. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your loop will never end - `while True` is going to be true forever, so print(m) is never executed